# file.write() the length of file without knowing the length of file beforehand - python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a header line that needs to be printed at the start of the textfile, and then the next line should contain the information about how many lines of data there are.

The final output file should contain the follow content:

1. the header line before the first `\n`
2. the length of file (i.e. # of lines in the before the 2nd `\n`
3. the unknown lines of string

The question is **how can (2) content be satisfied without first knowing how many lines of strings there are?**

I have been doing it as such:

1. write the header line
2. write a fake line of 50 `" "` characters
3. write unknown lines of string while keeping a counter of #lines
4. seek to the end of the header line
5. write the #line lines in the 2nd line, leave the rest of the `" "` untouch
6. close the file (imagine it goes up to 19GB worth of strings)

For the sake of example, i use `random.random()` to generate the number of lines, and i have been doing it this way:

```
import random
fout = open('testoverwrite','w')

header = "%% this is a header line"

print>>fout, header
print>>fout, "".join((" ")*50)

total = 0
numrows = int(100*random.random())
for i in range(numrows):
    j = int(100*random.random())
    total+=j
    print>>fout, j

fout.seek(len("%% this is a header line\n"))
#print len(str(numrows)+" "+str(total))
if len(str(numrows)+" "+str(total)) < 50:
    fout.write(str(numrows)+" "+str(total))

fout.close()
```

**is there are better way to do this?**

Comment: Why do you need to know the file length before you write anything out? Why do you print out? Are you listing the number of accounts, in a billing system for example?

Comment: Better to use `with open('testoverwrite','w') as fout:` for dealing with file IO.

Comment: because the output of this script is the input of another and the (2) condition is essential to determine the options in the next script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't understand **why** you want to do this, but if you must ;-)  For this to work cross-platform, `seek()` doesn't always work the way you think it works on files opened in text mode.  To get this to work reliably on text-mode files, you can only `seek()` to positions previously returned by `tell()`.  So, after you write your header line, do (e.g.):

```
print>>fout, header
pos = fout.tell()
```

`pos` may or may not equal `len(header) + 1` at this point (depends on the platform).  But seeking to it later **will** get to the start of the line following the header.  So replace your:

```
fout.seek(len("%% this is the header line\n"))
```

(which is pretty strange regardless, since that's not the header line you wrote before) with:

```
fout.seek(pos)
```

Then the next write will overwrite the leading characters in the file's second line.

Comment: sorry i was "trying" to be annon about what dataset i'm working with =), corrected the header seek.